# Handling n no of gif in collection view Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my project i have implemented a view with number of gif's loaded from API. All are grouped in a collection view. I have an issue here, App is unexpected quitting and in debugger I got intimation like "Terminated due to memory issue" like that.

So please help me on this to sort out the same. If third party library available to handle this will also fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you use objective C library  so i can gives you?

Comment: It is quite clear from the debug message that you are running out of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this library: https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher. It supports GIFs.
You can simply set link to your gif in your cellForItem method and this lib will handle the rest (including downloading and caching files):

```
let url = URL(string: "Your-Gif-URL")
cell.imageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Objective C library for avoid memory warning.

https://github.com/yfme/UIImageView-PlayGIF

**Sample Code Snippet**

```
        YFGIFImageView *launcherImageView =[[YFGIFImageView alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        launcherImageView.gifPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"matis.gif" ofType:nil];;
        launcherImageView.unRepeat = YES;

        launcherImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [self.window addSubview:launcherImageView];
        [launcherImageView startGIF];
```